# Slideshow by array using slice method

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

I made a slide show using array values, it works, but I strongly believe that the way I did is too long.

There should be an easier or more compact way to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var num = 0;
  var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"];
  var batch = 1;
  var value = 0;
  var tdLength = 5;
  var flag = true;
  var cal = 0;

  var showArray = function (num) {

    var required = myArray.slice(num, (num+5));
    $('.info').empty();

    $.each(required, function (item, n) {

      $('.info').append(
         '<h1>'+ n +'</h1>'
        )

    })

    //value += 5; 

  }


  function add(amount) {
    num = (num + tdLength - 1 + amount) % tdLength + 1

    cal = (num-1) * 5;
    //console.log(myArray.slice(cal, cal+5));
    showArray(cal);

  }

 $('#next-arrow').click(function(e){

   flag = true;

   if(cal >= (tdLength+5)) {
     $(e.target).css({ opacity:0.5 });
     return
   }
   $(e.target).css({ opacity:1});
   add(batch)


 }); 
 $('#prev-arrow').click(function(e){

   flag = false;

   if(cal <= 1) {
     $(e.target).css({ opacity:0.5 });
     return
   }

   $(e.target).css({ opacity:1});
   add(-batch)

 });

 $('#next-arrow').click();

})
```

HTML :

```
<div class="info">

    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <a href="#" id="prev-arrow">Previous</a>
      <a href="#" id="next-arrow">Next</a>

    </div>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8DcPdVfRvVFJNRJcKrSi?p=preview)

Comment: Both codes (here and live demo) are not the same, could you please update your question to put the code to review (for now I don't know if it's this one or the one from the live demo) ?

Comment: You work on the demo. that's ok. mean while I made some code change that's it. I am fine with demo code.

Comment: Hum, except that if we do a review on the demo code, it won't relate to the code in this question, making it hard to understand for potential viewers (since you can continue to modify the demo). Just copy the code you want a review on here, put a link to a demo if you want and work on a separate planker, to avoid any confusion possible.

Comment: ok. actually there is no difference between the live and the code what i pasted here.

Comment: In the demo, there is no *tdLength* variable, no dead code, no *flag* variable, no *cal* variable. Are you sure we are talking about the same demo code (the link at the end of your question) ?

Answer (score 2):

1. JavaScript does type conversion automatically, there is no need to create the `myArray` variable. You can do that entire bit using a `for` loop similar to this:

   ```
   var showArray = function (num) {
     $('.info').empty();
     for (var i = num; i < Math.max(num + 5, 13); ++i) {
       $('.info').append(`<h1>${n}</h1>`);
     }
   };
   ```

   (Maybe instead of hardcoding 13, you have a `const` for the length)
2. Keep your use of semicolons consistent. Either have them or don't. Pick a style convention and stick to it.